I found Azure's resource health alerts is extremely hard to understand
When configuring alert condition section for Azure Web App in Alert rule.
There are Current resource status and Previous resource status.
Both have 'Available' as an option, both give little info about what they achieve.
If I set both as  'Available', does it mean I will receive countless alerts because the normal status will trigger an alert or nothing?


When configuring an alert condition for a web app resource health, the main purpose of Current resource status and previous resource status is given below.
Current resource status:

Select the current resource status. Values are Available, Degraded, and Unavailable.

Previous resource status:

Select the previous resource status. Values are Available, Degraded, Unavailable, and Unknown.

Reference MSDoc for the above relevant information.
If you set both as 'Available', then you will not receive any countless alerts because the current resource status and previous resource status transition will not occur. (No state change)
In order to receive any alerts, you need to set previous current status as unavailable or degraded and set current resource status as available.

Once it is added, I have started receiving an alert triggered and action group mails as shown below.


So, it is just a comparison of status, the alert will be triggered if Current resource status and Previous resource status are set differently. Even if I set these two as Degraded,  since there is no transition, the alert still won't be triggered

Yes, that's right. @RistoLibera
